# MVC populate drop down list no postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, postback, html-select

Is their a way to populate a drop down list by pressing a button without post back.

Ex: dropdownlist1 -> a

press button

and populates dropdownlist2 with different data regarding dropdownlist1 value.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Most common scenario is generating the second dropdownlist values depending on the first DropDownList selected item changed. I assume that you are looking for the same scenario and below code is for achieve that. Let me know if you really need the button click to generate the second dropdown.

Model:

```
namespace MvcApplicationrazor.Models
{
    public class CountryModel
    {
        public List<State> StateModel { get; set; }
        public SelectList FilteredCity { get; set; }
    }
    public class State
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string StateName { get; set; }
    }
    public class City
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        public string CityName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            CountryModel objcountrymodel = new CountryModel();
            objcountrymodel.StateModel = new List<State>();
            objcountrymodel.StateModel = GetAllState();
            return View(objcountrymodel);
        }


        //Action result for ajax call
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult GetCityByStaeId(int stateid)
        {
            List<City> objcity = new List<City>();
            objcity = GetAllCity().Where(m => m.StateId == stateid).ToList();
            SelectList obgcity = new SelectList(objcity, "Id", "CityName", 0);
            return Json(obgcity);
        }
        // Collection for state
        public List<State> GetAllState()
        {
            List<State> objstate = new List<State>();
            objstate.Add(new State { Id = 0, StateName = "Select State" });
            objstate.Add(new State { Id = 1, StateName = "State 1" });
            objstate.Add(new State { Id = 2, StateName = "State 2" });
            objstate.Add(new State { Id = 3, StateName = "State 3" });
            objstate.Add(new State { Id = 4, StateName = "State 4" });
            return objstate;
        }
        //collection for city
        public List<City> GetAllCity()
        {
            List<City> objcity = new List<City>();
            objcity.Add(new City { Id = 1, StateId = 1, CityName = "City1-1" });
            objcity.Add(new City { Id = 2, StateId = 2, CityName = "City2-1" });
            objcity.Add(new City { Id = 3, StateId = 4, CityName = "City4-1" });
            objcity.Add(new City { Id = 4, StateId = 1, CityName = "City1-2" });
            objcity.Add(new City { Id = 5, StateId = 1, CityName = "City1-3" });
            objcity.Add(new City { Id = 6, StateId = 4, CityName = "City4-2" });
            return objcity;
        }
```

**View:**

```
@model MvcApplicationrazor.Models.CountryModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function GetCity(_stateId) {
        var procemessage = "<option value='0'> Please wait...</option>";
        $("#ddlcity").html(procemessage).show();
        var url = "/Test/GetCityByStaeId/";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            data: { stateid: _stateId },
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                var markup = "<option value='0'>Select City</option>";
                for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                    markup += "<option value=" + data[x].Value + ">" + data[x].Text + "</option>";
                }
                $("#ddlcity").html(markup).show();
            },
            error: function (reponse) {
                alert("error : " + reponse);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
<h4>
 MVC Cascading Dropdown List Using Jquery</h4>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StateModel, new SelectList(Model.StateModel, "Id", "StateName"), new { @id = "ddlstate", @style = "width:200px;", @onchange = "javascript:GetCity(this.value);" })
    <br />
    <br />
    <select id="ddlcity" name="ddlcity" style="width: 200px">

    </select>

    <br /><br />
  }
```